# What am I doing wrong in my code?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.plist"];

NSArray  *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:myPlistPath];

int count = 0; 
for (NSDictionary *dict in arr) { 
      count += dict.count; 
}

return count;
```

What am I doing wrong?

I get the following error with the above code: Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: WHen do you get the signal? at which line? have you stepped through the code in a debugger? I'm guessing `paths` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is usually a memory fault, possibly caused by a bad address.

Start by printing out `paths`, `documentsDirectory`, `myPListPath` and `arr` (the addresses, not the contents) immediately after you set them, to see if any of them have been set to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out myPListPath and verifying that the file it's referring to actually exists and is the correct format. If you ask me, chances are that on this line:

```
NSArray  *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:myPlistPath];
```

something is going wrong, and `arr` is getting set to null.